# React-native-arkit/ how to set the position with ARKit.Sprite

Tags: javascript, react-native, arkit, skspritenode

I'm using the react-native-arkit in my project, but there is a problem about the position of picture and video which I added in the View.
Please see below picture:
[image]

When I walk around, the picture and the video will follow me and always facing to me, but the other objects under the picture and video are will stay at the first place where generated.
[image]
I set the positions just like the other objects but I don't know why it will be like this, any one knows how to solve this problem ? 
[image]